# Approval Process with Attachments and Enable Email Approval Process - any workaround?

Tags: apex, configuration

I have an Approval Process on a custom object with the Process Automation setting 'Enable Email Approval Process' enabled. I want to submit a record for approval and the related attachment(s) to be attached to the approval email specified in the approval process. I have a trigger and helper class to take care of the auto-sending of attachments however, I haven't determined how this can successfully work yet with the 'enable email approval process' setting.

Unfortunately, as per this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4D3AAI), this is not standard Salesforce functionality and there doesn't seem a relatively straight forward way for me to hack around this in the sense that the 'reply to' address for approving records which can be approved via mobile always changes and isn't queryable anyway in Salesforce.

I came across this [really ingenious approach](https://hanlin-chen.com/2016/12/04/approval-email-with-attachments/) to hack around this by using Files object and links instead of Attachments, which looks appealing and may be even more helpful in the sense that some attachments can be large and if accessing via mobile while not connected to a network, downloading them may be expensive.

However, it's also a lot more code that is required. Is there another way to use attachments and approval processes with the 'Enable Email Approval Process'?

Comment: This sounds like a custom Email Service Class to me + another one to replace the standard email.
Unfortunately, I can't open the ingenious approach link :( connection refused

Comment: Does this work? https://salesforceprodigy.com/2016/12/04/approval-email-with-attachments/ Thanks.

Comment: I think the link you are looking at attaches files to the approval request, not process attachments sent back from the YES/APPROVED email response.

Comment: Link worked. Agree with @cropredy - seems a different usecase.

Comment: I don't need attachments sent back from the yes/no email response, I just need attachments sent from the approval process to recipients, who can then reply to the email and their response (no attachment) will write to the process step. An email service class won't be able to take care of this? Thanks everyone